# PHP get image src

Tags: php, src

```
$variable = '<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/66ce1f26a725b2e063d128457c20eda1?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" height="32" width="32" alt=""/>';
```

**How to get src of this image?**

Like:

`$src = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/66ce1f26a725b2e063d128457c20eda1?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG';`

Thanks.

Comment: Is there anything else in `$variable`, e.g. other HTML or just the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an html parser for this. See this one: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ (I hope this works for nodes, not just for entire pages).

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives that actually use DOM instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org). However, for the OP's UseCase, a HTML/DOM Parser might be overkill.

Answer (score 6):

use regex

```
preg_match( '@src="([^"]+)"@' , $variable , $match );
```

And src will be in $match, see print_r( $match ).
But this is only for this situation, if you want universal solution (like ' against " etc.) use html/DOM parser.

Comment: Actually one of the rare cases where I think a Regex is justified and better suited than a full blown HTML parser for getting to the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Use [HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). Download and include **simple_html_dom.php** file in your script.

Then get image URLs like this:

```
$html = str_get_html('<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/66ce1f26a725b2e063d128457c20eda1?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" height="32" width="32" alt=""/>');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';
```