# PHP single quotes regex

Tags: php, html, regex

This topic is a remark for [PHP get image src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510535/php-get-image-src)

So we have a variable with code inside (only image):

```
$image = "<img src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/66ce1f26a725b2e063d128457c20eda1?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG' height='32' width='32' alt=''/>";
```

**How can we get src of this image?** We should throw it to some new variable.

Want to use regex, tryed this (doesn't work):

```
preg_match('@src=\'([^"]+)\'@', $image, $src);
```

The problem is - there are single quotes instead of double quotes.

Finally, we must get:

```
$src = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/66ce1f26a725b2e063d128457c20eda1?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG';
```

Searching for a true regex.

---

If I use `'@src=\'([^"]+?)\'@'`, `print_r($src)` gives:

```
Array (
[0] => src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/66ce1f26a725b2e063d128457c20eda1?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG'
[1] => http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/66ce1f26a725b2e063d128457c20eda1?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
)
```

Don't need the first value in array.

Thanks.

Comment: $src = $src[1] ? I don't know what you mean. Use print_r( $src ) to see your array of matches, and get value you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `[^"]+` is being greedy.  To make it stop matching as soon as `'` is reached, use `[^"]+?`.

I assume you meant `[^']+`.  Writing this will also fix your problem.

Finally, assign `$src` to `$src[1]` to get the first grouped expression.

Comment: gives - Array ( [0] => src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/66ce1f26a725b2e063d128457c20eda1?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG' [1] => http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/66ce1f26a725b2e063d128457c20eda1?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG )

Comment: Greediness wouldn't be an issue if he just corrected the character class as you suggested.  By the way, the single-quote in the character class needs to be escaped like the others, i.e., `[^\']+`